# How to convert variables from version 2 to version 3 4 5 of pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript written in Version #2. I am trying to convert it to version #3~#5

I am having trouble converting this to version 3~5. Is there anyone that can convert this properly for me please?

```
//@version=2
strategy("signal1", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_value=50000, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, slippage=3, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075, pyramiding=0)
decay = atr(10)*0.005
stage1 = 7
stage2 = 15
stage3 = 35
p1 = input(5)
p2 = p1 + input(2)
p3 = input(0.01,step=0.001)

// 1day

Price=close

PriceTop=low
PriceBot=high

pretopvector01 = nz(topvector01[1], PriceTop)
topvector01 = PriceTop >= pretopvector01 ? PriceTop : pretopvector01 - (decay * topvector01finalcounter[1])
topvector01counter = n - valuewhen(PriceTop >= topvector01, n, 0)
topvector01finalcounter = topvector01counter <= p1 ? stage1 : topvector01counter <= p2 ? stage2 : stage3

prebotvector01 = nz(botvector01[1], PriceBot)
botvector01 = PriceBot <= prebotvector01 ? PriceBot : prebotvector01 + (decay * botvector01finalcounter[1])
botvector01counter = n - valuewhen(PriceBot <= botvector01, n, 0)
botvector01finalcounter = botvector01counter <= p1 ? stage1 : botvector01counter <= p2 ? stage2 : stage3

half=(topvector01[1]*2+botvector01[1])/3
col=half>=close 
sig=col ? topvector01 : botvector01

berate(a,b) =>
    ab=abs(1-a/b)

br_min=berate(sig,half)

comm_cond=br_min<p3 or br_min>br_min[1]
long_cond=close>sig and comm_cond
short_cond=close<sig and comm_cond

if long_cond
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
if short_cond
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)

bgcolor(strategy.position_size>0 ? lime : red)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in this script is it uses forward referencing which is [removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#forward-referenced-variables-are-removed) in v3.

Once you fix that, it should compile fine for v3. Then you can use the auto converter tool to upgrade to v5.

```
//@version=5
strategy('signal1', overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_value=50000, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, slippage=3, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075, pyramiding=0)
decay = ta.atr(10) * 0.005
stage1 = 7
stage2 = 15
stage3 = 35
p1 = input(5)
p2 = p1 + input(2)
p3 = input.float(0.01, step=0.001)

// 1day

Price = close

PriceTop = low
PriceBot = high

topvector01 = 0.0
topvector01finalcounter = 0.0
botvector01 = 0.0
botvector01finalcounter = 0.0

pretopvector01 = nz(topvector01[1], PriceTop)
topvector01 := PriceTop >= pretopvector01 ? PriceTop : pretopvector01 - decay * topvector01finalcounter[1]
topvector01counter = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(PriceTop >= topvector01, bar_index, 0)
topvector01finalcounter := topvector01counter <= p1 ? stage1 : topvector01counter <= p2 ? stage2 : stage3

prebotvector01 = nz(botvector01[1], PriceBot)
botvector01 := PriceBot <= prebotvector01 ? PriceBot : prebotvector01 + decay * botvector01finalcounter[1]
botvector01counter = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(PriceBot <= botvector01, bar_index, 0)
botvector01finalcounter := botvector01counter <= p1 ? stage1 : botvector01counter <= p2 ? stage2 : stage3

half = (topvector01[1] * 2 + botvector01[1]) / 3
col = half >= close
sig = col ? topvector01 : botvector01

berate(a, b) =>
    ab = math.abs(1 - a / b)
    ab

br_min = berate(sig, half)

comm_cond = br_min < p3 or br_min > br_min[1]
long_cond = close > sig and comm_cond
short_cond = close < sig and comm_cond

if long_cond
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
if short_cond
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)

bgcolor(strategy.position_size > 0 ? color.lime : color.red, transp=90)
```